# SearchBar delegate in UISearchController not work

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, searchbar

I'm trying to add a search bar to a view, but I've tried it a thousand ways and the searchbar delegate does not work.

```
class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

**The issue you are having is that UITableViewController has a big restriction:** its main view must be a UITableView that takes up the entire screen space (except for a possible navigation bar at the top, and a toolbar or tab bar at the bottom).

If your screen consists of just a  UITableView, then it makes sense to use it.  However, since you are adding a search bar, you must use a UIViewController and add a UITableView to it.  Then you can add the search bar as you like.

Comment: I tried it anyway and it is not delegating, the UISearchBarDelegate protocol failures do not work, I tried it in a UIViewController and nothing.